# what language is the initial compiler of typescript written in?

Tags: typescript, programming-languages

According to another thread on the same topic, typescript is a 'bootstrapped' language.

If typescript is a Bootstrapped language, it means that the initial compiler was written in an initial lower level language. Then what language would that have been?

from wikipedia:

> The TypeScript compiler is itself written in TypeScript, transcompiled
>   to JavaScript and licensed under the Apache 2 License.

Comment: If I would guess, probably Javascript? (Since TypeScript is a superset of Javascript, starting out with Javascript and gradually changing your code to TypeScript as the language changes would be very easy.)

Comment: I feel similarly to @Frxstrem, I know a few of the typescript core team members frequently post here (Ryan and Basarat) in particular, hopefully they can answer the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The earliest implementation of TypeScript started off in JavaScript.